# IE9-10 document mode switching on refresh

Tags: internet-explorer, doctype

I am observing the following behavior:

1. Navigate to a page in IE10 (maybe earlier versions)

   - The server serves an error page in **standards mode**.
   - It has an HTML5 doctype and an X-UA-Compatible meta tag.
2. Hit F5 in the browser to reload.

   - The server now serves an **IE5 quirks mode** page.
   - Whatever error happened has been resolved and you get the intended page.
   - <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
   - <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="**IE=5**">
   - (I don't control this)
3. The browser does not switch document modes as I might expected

   - IE **enters IE9 quirks mode** instead of IE5 quirks mode.

I am maintaining a legacy application with many pages that are beyond my control. The error page for the site is under my control and using HTML5 standards mode.

Is there a way to ensure that a quirks mode page loads in the intended mode in the described scenario? The alternative is to maintain a set of quirks mode error pages and write a hackish layer to detect which type of document would have been served if the error hadn't happened and serve an error page in that mode. Sad.